Web push notifications no longer received after turning iPhone back on
I'm working on a PWA developed with Angular and using Firebase Cloud Messaging.
Everything runs as expected when the device is on, notifications are received, showed and the app is opening when I click on the notification.
But if I turn the iPhone off, publish a notification then turn it back on again, the published notification is not showed on the notification center.
I'm using iOs 17.4.1.
Is there something I can do?
